# Continuous binary operations on $\beta\mathbb{N}$

Tags: gn.general-topology, stone-cech-compactification

It is well-known that the operation of addition of two ultrafilters on the set $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers which extends the natural addition on $\mathbb{N}$ to $\beta\mathbb{N}$, the Cech-Stone compactification of $\mathbb{N}$, is not continuous (it is only right-continuous).

I am thus looking for examples of continuous binary operations on $\beta\mathbb{N}$ i.e. such functions $\beta\mathbb{N}\times\beta\mathbb{N}\to\beta\mathbb{N}$ which are (jointly) continuous (not only separately continuous). I am only interested in operations that engage both variables (so e.g. projections and their compositions with mappings $\beta\mathbb{N}\to\beta\mathbb{N}$ drop out), but they need not have any additional properties like associativity etc.

Comment: Compact Hausdorff spaces possess exponentials (set of all continuous maps with compact-open topology). Moreover (here I am not 100% confident, that's why I am not making this an answer), the exponential $X^{\beta\mathbb N}$ is homeomorphic to the cartesian power $X^{\mathbb N}$ for any compact Hausdorff $X$. It follows that continuous maps ${\beta\mathbb N}\times{\beta\mathbb N}\to X$ are in one-to-one correspondence with *arbitrary* sequences of continuous maps $f_1,f_2,...:{\beta\mathbb N}\to X$

Comment: In other words (if the above is correct), any choice of values $f(i,j)$ on principal ultrafilters, (and these values might be arbitrary) extends uniquely to such an $f$.

Comment: ...which is impossible since ${\beta\mathbb N}\times{\beta\mathbb N}$ is [not](https://mathoverflow.net/a/277289/41291) homeomorphic to $\beta({\mathbb N}\times{\mathbb N})$ - so I do make a mistake somewhere, sorry...

Comment: The usual extension of addition is not jointly contínuous for this reason

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Although, when $X$ is compact Hausdorff, $X^{\beta\mathbb{N}}$ and $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ are isomorphic as sets, the topologies are different. The compact-open topology on $[0,1]^{\beta\mathbb{N}}$ is uniform convergence on compact sets, which by compactness of $\beta{\mathbb{N}}$ is just uniform convergence, whereas the topology coming from $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ is pointwise convergence on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @RobertFurber Aha so that's the place where I lied, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this paper, [Dimension phenomena associated with $\beta\mathbb{N}$-spaces](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0166-8641(01)00281-4), Ilijas Farah proved that continuous maps from $\beta\mathbb{N}^2$ (and other powers) to $\beta\mathbb{N}$ are quite simple: there is a finite disjoint cover such that the map depends on one coordinate on each member of the cover.

Comment: Thank you, KP! However, that's bitter news to me, unfortunately. Do you know whether there are similar results for operations on squares (that is, saying that operations $(\beta\mathbb{N})^2\to(\beta\mathbb{N})^2$ are also somehow simple)?

Comment: You can apply the result to each coordinate separately and take a common refinement of the two covers. Then each coordinate is simple on each member of the cover.

Comment: Also: Malykhin, in $\beta\mathbb{N}$  (https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=552052), shows that if $\prod_{n\in\omega}X_n$ contains a copy of $\beta\mathbb{N}$ then one of the factors already contains a copy.